# Finding c in parametric quadratic equation

Tags: parametric

I tried searching before posting this, but couldn't find anything. I have this parametric* equation :

$ x^2 + 54x + 5a^2 = 0 $

They are asking me to find the values of **a** for which the roots of the equation will be

$x_{1} = (1/5)x_{2}$

The things that I tried :

1. $ x_{1} + (1/5)x_{2} = (1/5)(-b/a) $
2. $x_{1} * (1/5)x_{2} = (1/5)(c/a)$

But I can't get to the right answer. If you don't feel like explaining just tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy of using the Vieta relations works quickly.

Let the roots be $r$ and $5r$.

Then the sum of the roots is $6r$. It is also $-54$, so $r=-9$.

The product of the roots is $5(-9)^2$. It is also $5a^2$. So $a^2=81$.

Comment: It did not came to me to do **r = actual_root** so when i tried with the actual roots it was not equal to -9... i guess i did not think hard enough